# Can I use an annotation inside a method body?

Tags: java, exception, annotations

Allows the semantics of Java annotations to place them somewhere **inside a functions body**, e.g. to annotate a specific function call, statement or expression?

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    void theFunc(Thing thing) {
        String s = null;
        @Catching(NullPointerException)   //<< annotation ?
          s = thing.getProp().getSub().getElem().getItem();
        if(s==null)
            System.out.println("null, you fool");
    }
}
```

To abbreviate the often written (too often, definitly!):

```
class MyClass {
    void theFunc(Thing thing) {
        String s = null;
        try {
            s = thing.getProp().getSub().getElem().getItem();
        } catch(NullPointerException ex) { }
        if(s==null) 
            System.out.println("null, you fool");            
    }
}
```

If the concept of this *embedded annotation* possible at all? Or something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ElementType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) specifies the valid targets of an annotation.  You can't annotate any old statement. It's basically narrowed down to declarations; declarations of:

- annotation type
- constructor
- field
- local variable
- method
- package
- parameter
- type