# <identifier> expected but I don't want use identifier

Tags: java, generics

This is my error message:

```
Set.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
        data = (T[]) new Object[10];
            ^
1 error
```

This is my code of Set.java.

```
public class Set<T>{

            private T[] data;
            private int used;
            private int capacity;

            public Set(){

                used = 0;
                capacity = 1024;
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                data = (T[]) new Object[10];
            }

            public int empty(){

                if(used == 0){
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return 0;
                }

            }
```

If I do `T[ ] data = (T[]) new Object[10];` the error gone. But I don't want use `T[ ]` because , I have done this already at data field which is `private T[] data;` So I want to use data field with `data = (T[]) new Object[10];`  not a new `T[ ] data`.But I take this error message. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just move the annotation and the initialization to the declaration. It doesn't depend on anything in the constructor. Same goes for the other two variables actually. Then you can remove the constructor. Don't write code you don't have to write.

```
public class Set<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T[] data = (T[]) new Object[10];
    private int used = 0;
    private int capacity = 1024;

    //constructor removed

    public int empty(){
        //...
```

Comment: Can you write spesific code? I can't understand without use some code.

Comment: @Michael I consider it a fair question. How am I to answer him properly without an accurate gauge of his comprehension level?

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot use annotations within a method body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949192/can-i-use-an-annotation-inside-a-method-body). If you want to ignore the warning, move the annotation to before the method declaration:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Set()
{
    used = 0;
    capacity = 1024;
    data = (T[]) new Object[10];
}
```